# How could I remove mysql from manually installation version

Tags: install, mysql

I manually installed the MySQL without homebrew

However, I still installed another mysql server by homebrew.

```
which mysql

/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

How could I remove the manual installed mysql server, thanks

[image: inline]

Answer (score 5):

To completely uninstall MySQL OS X it is necessary to remove numerous files and folders and edit one file.

To uninstall MySQL and completely remove it (including all databases) from your Mac do the following:

- Open a Terminal window
- Use mysqldump to backup your databases to text files!
- Stop the database server
- Remove files and folders:

  ```
  rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
  sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
  sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
  sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
  sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
  sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
  sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
  edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
  ```

Comment: It work with OS X Hight sierra and Mojave, for MySQL 5.7.x, does it with 8.x?