# Trouble running MySQL on OS X 10.9.5

Tags: command-line, homebrew, mysql

So I ran over a lot of post treating of this specific problem but none of the answer seems to work for my case.

So this is the process : 
I installed mysql via homebrew that lead me to this :

```
Marjorie:~ Mawel$ brew install mysql
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mysql-5.7.11.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql-5.7.11.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring mysql-5.7.11.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=Mawel --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11 --d
Last 15 lines from /Users/Mawel/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mysql/01.mysqld:
2016-04-03 22:00:14 +0200

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysqld
--initialize-insecure
--user=Mawel
--basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11
--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
--tmpdir=/tmp

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall mysql`
==> Caveats
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

To connect run:
    mysql -uroot

A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.

To load mysql:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  mysql.server start
```

I tried `mysql.server start`

```
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Marjorie.local.pid).
```

I looked for the file but the parent folder was empty :

```
Marjorie:mysql Mawel$ cd /usr/local/var/mysql/
Marjorie:mysql Mawel$ ls -all
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 Mawel  admin   68 Apr  3 22:27 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 Mawel  admin  170 Apr  3 22:00 ..
```

I then saw

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall mysql`
```

So I run it after giving acces right to it.

```
Marjorie:etc Mawel$ brew postinstall mysql
==> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=Mawel --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11 --d
Last 15 lines from /Users/Mawel/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mysql/01.mysqld:
2016-04-03 22:24:00 +0200

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysqld
--initialize-insecure
--user=Mawel
--basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11
--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
--tmpdir=/tmp


READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues
```

Still no changement at `mysql.server start`

Anybody could help me pls I really don't know what to do anymore :/

As a plus : here is my.conf (should I edit it ?)

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
# socket = .....

# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

# CUSTOMIZED BY MMVMySQL SCRIPT - JUST GENERIC SETTINGS
# DO NOT TREAT AS GOSPEL

innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
skip-name_resolve
max-connect-errors=100000
max-connections=500

#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
"my.cnf" [readonly] 170 lines, 4719 characters
```

### Edit

So after **klanomath** proposition I decided to clean all my mysql file and remove by the same time MAMP and MAMPro since they could be conflicting.

First step :

```
Marjorie:mysql Mawel$ brew uninstall mysql
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11... (12,817 files, 440.5M)
```

Then I ran `sudo find / -name mysql` and decided to clean it all :

```
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level/auto/DBD/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level/DBD/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql
find: ‘/dev/fd/3’: Not a directory
find: File system loop detected; ‘/dev/fd/4’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/dev/fd’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘/dev/fd/5’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/dev’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘/dev/fd/6’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/dev/fd’.
find: ‘/dev/fd/7’: Not a directory
find: ‘/dev/fd/8’: Not a directory
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/mysql
/private/var/mysql
/Users/Mawel/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mysql
/usr/local/var/mysql
```

I hard cleaned up this and finish with this :

```
Marjorie:/ Mawel$ sudo find / -name mysql
find: ‘/dev/fd/3’: Not a directory
find: File system loop detected; ‘/dev/fd/4’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/dev/fd’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘/dev/fd/5’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/dev’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘/dev/fd/6’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/dev/fd’.
find: ‘/dev/fd/7’: Not a directory
find: ‘/dev/fd/8’: Not a directory
```

And finally I ran again `brew install mysql`

And same problem came up :

> Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully You can
>   try again using `brew postinstall mysql`

And same schema again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homebrew mysql install (or better: the initialization) failed. The main data dir is empty. Usually the data dir looks like this after a fresh install:

```
drwxr-xr-x   18 user  admin  -      612  4 Apr 04:04 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 user  admin  -      102  4 Apr 04:04 ..
-rw-r-----    1 user  admin  -       56  4 Apr 04:04 auto.cnf
-rw-------    1 user  admin  -     1680  4 Apr 04:04 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r--    1 user  admin  -     1075  4 Apr 04:04 ca.pem
-rw-r--r--    1 user  admin  -     1079  4 Apr 04:04 client-cert.pem
-rw-------    1 user  admin  -     1680  4 Apr 04:04 client-key.pem
-rw-r-----    1 user  admin  -      407  4 Apr 04:04 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r-----    1 user  admin  - 50331648  4 Apr 04:04 ib_logfile0
-rw-r-----    1 user  admin  - 50331648  4 Apr 04:04 ib_logfile1
-rw-r-----    1 user  admin  - 12582912  4 Apr 04:04 ibdata1
drwxr-x---   77 user  admin  -     2618  4 Apr 04:04 mysql
drwxr-x---   90 user  admin  -     3060  4 Apr 04:04 performance_schema
-rw-------    1 user  admin  -     1680  4 Apr 04:04 private_key.pem
-rw-r--r--    1 user  admin  -      452  4 Apr 04:04 public_key.pem
-rw-r--r--    1 user  admin  -     1079  4 Apr 04:04 server-cert.pem
-rw-------    1 user  admin  -     1680  4 Apr 04:04 server-key.pem
drwxr-x---  108 user  admin  -     3672  4 Apr 04:04 sys
```

So it's no wonder that `mysql.server start` fails (or fails to stop mysql) because neither /usr/local/var/mysql/Marjorie.local.pid nor any other required file is present.

---

Probably you have an older mysql install or an old config file somewhere or mysql is even still running. Remove any mysql related file after dumping any current database or backing up/renaming config files. Don't forget to remove old mysql StartUp items or launch daemons and/or launch agents also in ~/Library/LaunchAgents!

Uninstall Oracle MySQL: [How could I remove mysql from manually installation version](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230339/93229)

Uninstall MAMP/MAMP Pro: Remove the MAMP and MAMP Pro folder

Also uninstall homebrew mysql. Then re-install homebrew mysql from scratch.

Comment: I checked if mysql was running it was all down; so this must be an older mysql installation running in conflict but I've erised most of it if it is not allready all of it .. Can you link me a page to help me finish it ?
I did it the hard way like `rm -rf mysql*` (basically)

Comment: Shall I remove every file find through `sudo find / -name mysql` ?
Most of them are from MAMP, is there no pb removing it ?

Comment: @Baldráni MAMP is self-containing and you can simply remove it. The homebrew mysql has to be removed with `brew uninstall mysql`. I don't recommend using `rm ... mysql*` for other older installations if you don't exactly know what you are doing. [Link uninstall Oracle mysql](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230339/93229)

Comment: Well I've edited my question if you can have look :)

Comment: @Baldráni Did you also rename/move/remove any mysql plist and my.cnf?

Comment: Yup just tried again removing them, allmost hesitating to cleaninstall this computeur

Comment: @Baldráni Then uninstall homebrew mysql **and** homebrew and execute `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`. Then reinstall homebrew/mysql. It may be sufficient to uninstall mysql only.

Comment: Ok I juste completly removed homebrew and retry the installation but no differrence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37911/discussion-between-klanomath-and-baldrani).